# alternative permutation of two lists

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get a alternative permutation of two list with no fixed length for example:

```
x = ["a","b","c"]
y = [1,2,3]
```

should return:

```
[(a,1),(b,2),(c,3)] , [(a,2),(b,3),(c,1)], [(a,3),(b,1),(c,2)]
```

with list comprehensions I was able to get this:

```
[(x,y) | x<-x, y<-y ]

[("a",1),("a",2),("a",3),("b",1),("b",2),("b",3),("c",1),("c",2),("c",3)]
```

which is not exactly what I want

Comment: Using [`Data.List.permutations`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:permutations) and `zip` should get you there.

Comment: Oh, is there a reason you're only considering half of the permutations of [1,2,3]?  (e.g. [3,2,1] isn't present)

Comment: The importance for me is that every letter is matched to every number, there order in the list is not important, e.g. [(a,1),(b,2),(c,3)] == [(c,3),(b,2),(a,1)]

Comment: ah, yes but you seem to have missed the matching `[(a,3),(b,2),(c,1)]`, as well as two others, in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to permute one of your two lists, then pair up each permutation with the other list in the original order:

```
import Data.List (permutations)

bijections :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a, b)]]
bijections xs ys = map (zip xs) (permutations ys)
```

What this does is it generates all permutations of `ys` (so that would be `[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]` for your example) and then for each of them, it pairs them up with `xs` in its original order.